# Removing all the trailing zeroes of a numeric column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this table `properties` which has a column `atomic_mass` of type `NUMERIC(9,6)`:

```
 atomic_mass 
-------------
    1.008000
    4.002600
    6.940000
    9.012200
   10.810000
   12.011000
   14.007000
   15.999000
    1.000000
(9 rows)
```

So, I want to remove all the trailing zeros of the column such as 1.008, 4.0026, etc.
So, I tried to do the following:

```
UPDATE properties SET atomic_mass=trim(trailing '0' from atomic_mass::text)::numeric;
```

But, it's not working. I tested the `trim` function which works fine. If I type

```
SELECT trim(trailing '0' from atomic_mass::text)::numeric from properties
```

it returns

```
rtrim  
--------
  1.008
 4.0026
   6.94
 9.0122
  10.81
 12.011
 14.007
 15.999
      1
```

The column that I wanted. So, what is it that I am doing wrong here?
I am using PostgreSQL 12.9.

Comment: That's not a problem with the stored values, it's a problem how your SQL client (or application) _displays_ those values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the column as `NUMERIC(9,6)`. From here [Numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) that is `NUMERIC(precision, scale)`, where `scale` is :

> The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point.

So running `trim` to update the values is not going to help as the column definition `scale` will override that. The trailing zeros is a formatting issue that will have to be dealt with on output.

**UPDATE**

Given the information in your comments to this answer about being able to change the column type:

```
create table numeric_test (num_fld numeric, num6_fld numeric(9,6));
insert into numeric_test values (12.011000, 12.011000), (4.002600, 4.002600), (1.000000, 1.000000);

select * from numeric_test ;
  num_fld  | num6_fld  
-----------+-----------
 12.011000 | 12.011000
  4.002600 |  4.002600
  1.000000 |  1.000000

update numeric_test set num_fld = trim(trailing '0' from num_fld::text)::numeric, num6_fld = trim(trailing '0' from num6_fld::text)::numeric ;

select * from numeric_test ;
 num_fld | num6_fld  
---------+-----------
  12.011 | 12.011000
  4.0026 |  4.002600
       1 |  1.000000

--
insert into numeric_test values (9.012200, 9.012200);

select * from numeric_test ;
 num_fld  | num6_fld  
----------+-----------
   12.011 | 12.011000
   4.0026 |  4.002600
        1 |  1.000000
 9.012200 |  9.012200
```

With the unconstrained `numeric` you can remove trailing zeros from existing values on an update that trims them. However you will still get them if they are included in a insert or update that does not trim them.

Comment: So I should first convert it to decimal or something? Or the result would be the same?

Comment: `decimal` and `numeric` are the same thing. Read the information at the link I posted in the answer, it will answer a great many questions.

Comment: actually this a part of freecodecamp's RDB challenge where the task is "You should remove all the trailing zeros after the decimals from each row of the atomic_mass column. You may need to adjust a data type to DECIMAL for this. Be careful not to change the value".

Comment: well I solved it by changing the data type to REAL using the command "ALTER TABLE properties ALTER COLUMN atomic_mass TYPE REAL"

Comment: 1) `REAL` != `DECIMAL` 2) `REAL` is a float type and are: "The data types real and double precision are inexact, variable-precision numeric types. ..". So you have changed the value. Also: "When rounding values, the numeric type rounds ties away from zero, while (on most machines) the real and double precision types round ties to the nearest even number. "

Comment: See my **UPDATE** to answer.

Comment: The update statement will trim trailing zeroes from the integer part as well in some cases. If the input num_fld is 10 then it will be trimmed to 1.

Comment: The question was about dealing with `numeric` fields not `integers`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not change type to REAL they asked to change it to DECIMAL. So if you change it to DECIMAL only not DECIMAL(9,6) it will work.
Here is what worked for me:[image]

Comment: I solved it months ago. There was some bug maybe in FCC part. But they fixed it afterwards

Answer (score 2):

After converting to decimal type, you can also type the following:

UPDATE properties SET atomic_mass = atomic_mass::REAL;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajziT.png)

Hope it helps!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajziT.png)

Comment: Well I solved it months ago, but yes used your solution.

Answer (score 0):

just change the type `real` from `decimal`.

```
alter table properties alter column atomic_mass type real;
```