# Cast to show a suitable result

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have a query returning one of:

```
0.00 ,
0.05 ,
0.10
```

But I want the result as below instead of the above items:

```
0 ,
0.05 ,
0.1
```

Which cast or round is suitable to reach this result?

Comment: Not voting to close so I won't dup-hammer by mistake, but IIUC, this should solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72033248/2422776

Comment: After  year on stackoverflow, you should know how to format your questions...

Comment: Please post the query you have. This question is not answerable if you don't at least tell us what type this result column has - it is a `text`, a `decimal`, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers.
first I cast as numeric(2,2) and then cast the total result to float

Comment: Why would you ever use a float? Especially when you start with numeric. And slightly offtopic, presentation of data should imho be done in the presentation layer, not in the database nor application layer.

Comment: You *"first cast to `numeric(2,2)`"*, but what's the original data type before casting?  What's the range of possible values? Negative values? Is this only for representation, or is the result stored? What's your version of Postgres. Would a dangling dot ('.') be acceptable in '0.'?

Answer (score 0):

```
 to_char(n, 'FM90.99')
```

The [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) function takes any numeric input (there are overloaded variants for datetime types, too) and returns a *string* (type `text`) according to the given [template pattern](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE). For ***representation***.

If your input can overflow `numeric(2,2)`, then extend the pattern accordingly. For `numeric(9,6)`:

```
 to_char(n, 'FM999999990.999999')
```

The [template pattern modifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERICMOD-TABLE) `FM` for numeric input does this:

> fill mode (suppress trailing zeroes and padding blanks)

Sadly, it misses one spot: numbers with no significant fractional digits retain a dangling dot: *'0.'* or *'123.'*. If that's unacceptable, use one of these:

```
 rtrim(to_char(n, 'FM90.99'), '.')
 CASE n = 0 THEN '0' ELSE to_char(n, 'FM90.99') END
 to_char(n, 'FM90.99')::numeric
 n::float8
 n::real
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qQqNNcgN)

Each has pros and cons, and the result can vary subtly (or even fail) for corner cases. Most notably, only the top two return `text` ...